# Flush top, center, flush bottom in an array

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

In an array there are three options `r`, `c`, `l` for flushing `r`ight, `c`entered and flushing `l`eft. But how about flushing up and down and centered vertically? As an example in the array below, I want the left entry be centered vertically and not to be up!

```
\[\begin{array}{cc}
        \begin{array}{c}
        \xymatrix{A\ar[r] & A\ar[r] & A}
        \end{array} & \xymatrix{ & A & \\
        A\ar[ur]\ar[r]\ar[dr] & A & A\ar[ul]\ar[l]\ar[dl]\\
        & A & }
        \end{array}\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) can be used to provide a vertical alignment adjustment via the `valign` key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xypic,adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \adjustbox{valign=c}{\xymatrix{A\ar[r] & A\ar[r] & A}} &
      \adjustbox{valign=c}{\xymatrix{ & A & \\
        A\ar[ur]\ar[r]\ar[dr] & A & A\ar[ul]\ar[l]\ar[dl] \\
        & A & }}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

The vertical *anchor* is repositioned to the `c`entre of the construction.

Comment: Is it possible to have to \xymatrix under each other in adjustbox like array by using something like \\ ?

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: Sure. Put whatever you like in a n `array`, and wrap that inside an `\adjustbox`.